# Restrict all the special characters through a regex

Tags: c#, regex

There is a long set of characters that are not allowed to validate an input box of winform app.

So i figured that rather than making the long list that are not allowed make the shorter one that are allowed.

The set that is allowed are `(a-z,A-Z, 0-9,@,.)` .Rest every thing that can be entered are not allowed.

This is the regex that i have made for this.

```
Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"[@\.\w]+$")
```

It seem to work in some cases but when i enter the data in this format `normal character or number special character normal character or number` it seems to break few example `ee(vv, 55)44,aba&3B`.

Not able to figure out whats wrong in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is not valid, because you don't validate all string, but the last part.
You should start it with `^` - beginning of the line symbol.

```
Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^[\w@.]*$")
```

`\w` also means letters in every language, so it will validate the string `"абц"` too.
So if you need only for english, use

```
Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9@.]*$")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9@.]*$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9  _  -  \. @]*
```

as the Regex expression text.